# Circular import of SQLAlchemy models in one-to-many relationship in flask app

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, backend, flask-sqlalchemy

In my flask app I have two SQLAlchemy models which have one-to-many relationship.
It creates an error of circular imports, which actually happens and I see why it does, but I cannot find the solution of how to fix it.

db = SQLAlchemy() initialization I created in separate file and import it where it's needed

Both models are imported separately from different files.

```
from models.tag import TagModel
from models.person import PersonModel
from db import db

class ActionModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'actions'

    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    action = db.Column(db.String(80))
    category = db.Column(db.String(80))
    description = db.Column(db.String(100))
    tag = db.relationship(TagModel, backref='action',
                          uselist=False, lazy=True)
    # one-to-many relationship
    persons = db.relationship(PersonModel, back_populates="action")



from db import db
from models.action import ActionModel

class PersonModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String)
    action_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('actions.id'))
    action = db.relationship(
        ActionModel, back_populates='persons', lazy='dynamic')
```

Here You can see the function in POST method which creates an error. The issue is between ActionModel and PersonModel:

```
from db import db
from models.person import PersonModel
from models.tag import TagModel

blp = Blueprint('actions', __name__, description="Operation on actions")

@blp.route('/allActions', methods=['POST', 'GET', 'PUT'])
def add_action():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(1)
        id_action = str(uuid.uuid4())
        id_tag = str(uuid.uuid4())
        id_persons = str(uuid.uuid4())
        try:
            add_action_request = ActionSchema(**request.json)
            action_data = add_action_request.dict()
            action_data['id'] = id_action
            name = ''
            last_name = ''
            action_data['persons'] = {name: name,
                                      last_name: last_name, id: id_persons}

            tag_data = action_data.pop('tag')
            tag_data['id'] = id_tag
            new_tag = TagModel(**tag_data)
            print(action_data)

            new_person = PersonModel(action_data.pop('persons'))

            new_action = ActionModel(**action_data)
            new_action.tag = new_tag
            new_action.persons = new_person

            db.session.add(new_action)
            db.session.commit()
            return jsonify({'success': True})
        except ValidationError as e:
            return e
```

The error is like this:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ActionModel' from partially initialized module 'models.action' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\todoapp\flask_react\backend\models\action.py)

How should I change my files / imports organization or code itself to fix it?

Comment: Must you split each class into a separate file like Java? It's not necessary, though, I guess, you do you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having to import your models for your models' `relationship()`'s, you can use the string name of your model: e.g.

```
class PersonModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    ...
    action = db.relationship(
        "ActionModel", back_populates='persons', lazy='dynamic')
```